# Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine

Tags: botframework

When I try to install the Nuget package:

Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine

I get the following error:

Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine 1.0.2 constraint: Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime (>= 1.8.2 && < 2.0.0)'.

Comment: In the project that you are trying to install the DirectLine Nuget package; is already a reference to the Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime assembly?

Comment: Yes, there is a reference to version: 2.0.0.0 / runtime version v4.0.30319

Comment: Then that's the main problem. DirectLine enforces a version >= 1.8.2 and minor of 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems you already have a the Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime assembly in your solution and that the version you have is higher than the one enforced by the DirectLine NuGet.

I cannot comment about your solution and why you are using Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, but the first thing I would recommend is to remove the current Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime assembly (v 2.0.0), then install the DirectLine NuGet and then test your solution to check if the previous component that was using Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime can still works with a version < than 2.0.0

Comment: Thank you. To solve the problem I uninstalled Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime and re-installed Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime version 1.8. Then I was able to install Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine. I will try to raise a GitHub issue on the Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine site.